# Duvidas com carrossel jssor

Tags: java, jquery, css

eu estou usando o carrossel para na minha pagina, segue imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

até ai tudo bem , o problema é quando eu abro ele em celular, ele vai diminuindo o carrossel , e eu queria q ele jogac para baixo , segue imagem
vou mandar o css dele

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
      <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
                [{b: 5500, d: 3000, o: -1, r: 240, e: {r: 2}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1, c: {x: 51.0, t: -51.0}}, {b: 0, d: 1000, o: 1, c: {x: -51.0, t: 51.0}, e: {o: 7, c: {x: 7, t: 7}}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1, sX: 9, sY: 9}, {b: 1000, d: 1000, o: 1, sX: -9, sY: -9, e: {sX: 2, sY: 2}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1, r: -180, sX: 9, sY: 9}, {b: 2000, d: 1000, o: 1, r: 180, sX: -9, sY: -9, e: {r: 2, sX: 2, sY: 2}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1}, {b: 3000, d: 2000, y: 180, o: 1, e: {y: 16}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1, r: -150}, {b: 7500, d: 1600, o: 1, r: 150, e: {r: 3}}],
                [{b: 10000, d: 2000, x: -379, e: {x: 7}}],
                [{b: 10000, d: 2000, x: -379, e: {x: 7}}],
                [{b: -1, d: 1, o: -1, r: 288, sX: 9, sY: 9}, {b: 9100, d: 900, x: -1400, y: -660, o: 1, r: -288, sX: -9, sY: -9, e: {r: 6}}, {b: 10000, d: 1600, x: -200, o: -1, e: {x: 16}}]
            ];

            var jssor_1_options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,
                $SlideDuration: 800,
                $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
                $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                    $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
                },
                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
                },
                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
                }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1920);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                } else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>

    <style>

        /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssorb05 div           (normal)
        .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
        .jssorb05 .av           (active)
        .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
        .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
        */
        .jssorb05 {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
            position: absolute;
            /* size of bullet elment */
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background: url('img/b05.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .jssorb05 div { background-position: -7px -7px; }
        .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover { background-position: -37px -7px; }
        .jssorb05 .av { background-position: -67px -7px; }
        .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover { background-position: -97px -7px; }

        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 22 css */
        /*
        .jssora22l                  (normal)
        .jssora22r                  (normal)
        .jssora22l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora22r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora22l.jssora22ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora22r.jssora22rdn      (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora22l, .jssora22r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 40px;
            height: 58px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('img/a22.png') center center no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora22l { background-position: -10px -31px; }
        .jssora22r { background-position: -70px -31px; }
        .jssora22l:hover { background-position: -130px -31px; }
        .jssora22r:hover { background-position: -190px -31px; }
        .jssora22l.jssora22ldn { background-position: -250px -31px; }
        .jssora22r.jssora22rdn { background-position: -310px -31px; }
    </style>
```